# Open all folds matching a pattern in vim

Tags: vim

I'm using vim's syntax folding to look at a large GeoJSON file:

[image: Collapsed GeoJSON file]

If I type `/properties<ENTER>`, it unfolds everything on the path down to the first Feature's properties:

[image: Expanded properties]

Now if I hit `n` a bunch of times, it will go through the file and expand all the `properties` fields.

I'd like to do this in a single command. I've tried `:g/"properties": {/foldopen` but this only opens the path to the `properties` fields, not the `properties` fields themselves:

[image: Mostly expanded, need one more level]

How can I get this `:g` command to expand the properties fields, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:foldopen` just opens a single level of folding. Now if you use `:foldopen!` (with `!`), it will open *all* folds. But I think this still isn't what you want, because if you start with everything folded into one big fold, each and every fold will be opened (so you could just do `zR`). What you want is opening all folds to be able to see the current (searched for) line; `zv` does that:

```
:g/"properties": {/normal! zv
```

If you want all subfolds opened as well, use `normal! zvzO` instead.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Could you elaborate on what the `normal! ` means in that command?

Comment: `zv` is a normal mode command, there is no corresponding `:fold...` command, so we need to temporarily go into normal mode.